# How to show time evolution operator obeys causality?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, causality, time-evolution, wightman-fields

If we are given a time evolution function $K_t(\phi,\phi')$ which give the amplitude for a field starting in confiruation $\phi$ to go to configuration $\phi'$ after time t. What is the condition that $K$ satisfies causality and Lorentz invariance. (i.e. no signal can travel faster than light?). $\phi$ values of fields in 3 dimensions that satisfies some Lorentz invariant field equation.